# Aprentar boton y traer un componente en React

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

Estoy ocupando React y también Bootstrap

```
<Button
           Style=" margin: 20px"
           onClick = {() => {
            return(
            <Medico2/>
             ); }}
           >
             Agendar Hora a Paciente
           </Button>
```

esto hice en el return del render, necesito que cuando aprieto el botón aparezca en el componente "Medico2". Pero al presionar el botón no pasa nada, pero sí funciona el botón cuando le agrego un console.log(), manda a consola sin problemas. Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? De ante manos gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que estas insertando un componente en "la nada". Tienes que insertarlo en el código del return. Para manejar estados utiliza utiliza Hooks (https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), son tremendamente útiles.

Explicación del ejemplo:

- El Hook **pulsado** es **false** y por lo tanto en la condición `{pulsado...` se meterá en la parte de `Adios`.
- Cuando pulses el botón, el hook cambiará de estado y ahora se meterá en la parte de `Componente1`
- Cuando vuelvas a pulsar el botón se volvera a cambiar el estado...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


const Componente1 = () => (
  <h1>Hola</h1>
);


export default function App() {

  const [pulsado, setPulsado] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        Style=" margin: 20px"
        onClick = {() => setPulsado(!pulsado)}
        >
          Agendar Hora a Paciente
      </Button>
      {pulsado ? (
        <Componente1 />
      ) : (
        <h1>Adios</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```